# Activate method on router link click in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am working on account removal on a Chrome extension and I have the following button:

```html
<button @click="remove" id="button_remove" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;">Remove Account</button>
```

**JS**

```
methods:{
    remove(event){
       app.removeAccountData(url,apikey);
    }
},
```

I also have this `router-link`:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'RemovedWId', params: { accountid: chosenAccount.apikey}}" text="delete_account"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 2px; cursor: pointer;"></span> Remove Account</router-link>
```

Is there a way to use the `router-link` with the `JS` function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

##### Vue 2

With Vue Router 3, `<router-link>` is a component wrapper around `<a>`, so we'll need to use the [`.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) modifier for it to properly receive the event:

```html
<router-link @click.native="removeAccount" to="/remove">Remove</router-link>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-click-handler-on-router-link?file=src%2FApp.vue)

##### Vue 3

With Vue Router 4, `<router-link>` no longer passes its attributes and event handlers to its inner component, and Vue 3 no longer supports the `.native` event modifier. You'd have to apply the `@click` handler manually via `<router-link>`'s [custom default slot](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-s-v-slot).

1. Apply [`<router-link>`'s `custom` prop](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#custom) to enable the default slot customization.
2. In the `<router-link>`'s default slot, add an `<a>` and bind the following slot props:

   a. **`href`** (*the resolved URL to the route*) to `<a>.href`

   b. **`navigate`** (*the method that performs the navigation to the route*) to `<a>.@click`. Pass `navigate` and the `$event` (a special argument) to a method that runs the secondary method and then the `navigate()` method with `$event` as the argument.

```html
<router-link to="/remove" custom v-slot="{ href, navigate }">
  <a :href="href" @click="wrapNavigate(navigate, $event)">Remove</a>
</router-link>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    removeAccount() {
      // ...
    },
    wrapNavigate(navigate, event) {
      this.removeAccount()
      navigate(event)
    },
  },
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-click-handler-on-router-link?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Another Vue2 caveat: Keep in mind the `@click.native` event may not consistently occur before-or-after the `router-link` click event (depending on browser ie Edge vs Firefox vs Chrome, etc). In my case I was trying to grab route data on the click handler, but route data would differ if route change had already occurred by the time my click logic ran. In the end, I had to leverage `vue-router`'s navguards and a custom global store.

Comment: Lots of relevant discussion on this here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/974

Comment: This seems to work for Vue 3 and Vue Router 4 

<RouterLink :to="{ name: 'RemovedWId' }" @click="remove" />

Comment: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-click-handler-on-router-link-dzsbsc?file=src/App.vue) <RouterLink to="/about" @click="this.sayHello()"> yolo</RouterLink>