# Show or hide offcanvas menu when router link is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue electron app where the main menu template is loaded inside the `App.vue` file. I want to hide it when a `<router-link>` is clicked. It's an offcanvas menu so only the hamburger button is always displayed in all the components and the content will be showed only when the button is clicked. Is there any valid solution to manage this?

This is a sample of the menu markup that is inside the main view loaded inside the `App.vue` file

```
<template>
<div>
 <nav v-if="isVisible">
  <button @click.prevent="toggleMenu()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
  <li><router-link to="/"></router-link></li>
  <li><router-link to="/link-one"></router-link></li>
 </nav>
 <router-view></router-view>
</div> 
</template>

<script>
export {
 methods: {
  toggleMenu() {
   this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

At the moment the offcanvas content will remain on screen also after the router view will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use click.native?
Did a quick search on stackoverflow, looks like click on router-link will trigger click.native
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230500/13703967

```js
<template>
<div>
 <nav v-if="isVisible">
  <button @click.prevent="toggleMenu()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
  <li><router-link to="/" @click.native="toggleMenu"></router-link></li>
  <li><router-link to="/link-one" @click.native="toggleMenu"></router-link></li>
 </nav>
 <router-view></router-view>
</div> 
</template>

<script>
export {
 methods: {
  toggleMenu() {
   this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }
 }
}
</script>
```