# on click method with vue-router 4

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

With vue-router 3, it was possible to add a method on `router-link` with `@click.native="myMethod"` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230500/2112538).

In vue 3 the `.native` modifier [was deprecated](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html#overview).

When a user clicks on `<router-link to="somewhere" @click="myMethod">Click me</router-link>`,
it creates a bug where the entire app reloads.

With [vue-router 4](https://next.router.vuejs.org/), what is the correct way to trigger a method on click on a `router-link` tag?

Comment: This is most likely because you are overwriting the default @click handler on the `<a>` tag of `<router-link>` by putting your own @click handler there.

Whoever worked on `<router-link>` was aware that your issue will occur though: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/4142871189dbb13e1ce2d6be8d82bd5aa27526a3/src/RouterLink.ts#L199  

I tried doing something like `<router-link v-slot="{ navigate }" @click="() => { myMethod(); navigate;}` but you can't immediately use slot scope on the element you pulled it out from

Comment: Ah I asked on the Vue Discord channel for vue-router and Mr Posva (vue-router maintainer) said the code I linked is not released yet. After it's released you should be able to just use the code you provided in your original post (<router-link @click>, without .native, since it'll be implicitly passed through to <a> as native anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `vue-router` version is at least 4.0.6 (run `npm show vue-router` or `npm outdated`). In that version, there's a fix that allows doing what you're trying to achieve. Basically, the piece of code in your question should just work now.

So like:

```html
<template>
  <router-link to="/somePath" @click="myMethod()">Click me</router-link>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      console.log('hello');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's a runnable snippet with Vue 3 and the newest vue router 4

```js
const App = {
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <router-view />
      <router-link to="/hello" @click="myMethod()">Link (click me)</router-link>
      Did my method run: {{didMyMethodRun}}
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      didMyMethodRun: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      this.didMyMethodRun = true
    }
  }
}
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: {template: 'You are now on default route'}},
    {path: '/hello', component: {template: 'You are now hello route'}},
  ]
})
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
<html>
 <body>
   <div id="app"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Link to CHANGELOG](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/commit/4037749afbd7d50786baa6718d5e632e2a8af17f#diff-06572a96a58dc510037d5efa622f9bec8519bc1beab13c9f251e97e657a9d4edR5)

Comment: yes this was a bug in vue-router previous versions, thank you